# Created rest ressource in Hapijs

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, hapi.js, supertest

I'm building a *node* REST API server built with `hapi.js`, for a CRUD ressource, and for the Ressource creation, I want to set the location header and status code using `created` rather than `code(201).header('location....`

According the current API [Documentation](http://hapijs.com/api#response-object),

> created(uri) - sets the HTTP status code to Created (201) and the HTTP 'Location' header where: uri - an absolute or relative URI used as the 'Location' header value.

However, when I try to do a post method on my request, **BOOM**, some exception.

> Debug: internal, implementation, error
>   TypeError: Uncaught error: undefined is not a function

suggesting that the property/method doesn't really exist.

(hapi is still evoluting, and most blogpost refer to an old request.reply...)

---

*How should I do then?*

Here is the route:

```
{
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/api/myressource',
     config: {
         handler: function (request, reply) {
             // creation logic
             reply.created("/created/path");
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I should have read a bit more of the [documentation](http://hapijs.com/api#reply-interface)...

`reply` is a callback, not the reply object. (*feeling java background...*)

So what I needed to do was: `reply().created("/created/path");`

Comment: `reply()` isn't actually a promise, it's callback function, it's called on process.nextTick() though, so you can add headers like created after it's called :)

Comment: indeed, still need to make progress on js terminology :)